# How to include hbci4java (a java ANT project hosted on github) into a SBT scala application?

Tags: git, scala, maven, ant, sbt

I'm writing a scala application (playframework 2.3.1) and want to use hbci4java (https://github.com/willuhn/hbci4java).

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a place where hbci4java is available from a maven server (see thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/hbci4java/FdZ7ESR5cnA), but the project's git repository contains a pom.xml file and a build.xml for Ant.

What is the easiest way for me to use this library?

I tried (Build.scala):

```
val hbci4java = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/willuhn/hbci4java.git"))
val myMainProject = [...].dependsOn(hbci4java)
```

That compiled fine and the compiler output says

```
[info] Updating {https://github.com/willuhn/hbci4java.git}hbci4java...
```

but it doesn't say more about it. No compiling of the classes there.
And it also didn't make the hbci4java classes available in my project. I assume it tries to find an sbt project on git and doesn't work since hbci4java isn't an sbt project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two possibilities:

- Compile the library yourself (using Maven) and include it in your project as an [unmanaged dependency](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html) in the lib directory. You will have to track sub-dependencies yourself.
- Compile the library yourself and publish it on your own Maven repository using `mvn release`. Then add a managed dependency on the version in that repository. Only people with access to that repository can build the project.

When you look in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/willuhn/hbci4java/blob/master/pom.xml) of hbcj4java, you will see that it has only a test dependency on JUnit. So adding it as an unmanaged dependency should be easy: Just add the JAR file into the lib directory -- no other steps are required.